# Can't load spacemacs - it's trying to delete pspp-mode

Tags: spacemacs, package

I am a vim user who only uses emacs for my org-mode todo file, so I really don't know what I'm doing. After updating Ubuntu to 19.04 (and thereby updating emacs to 26.x), I'm getting an error when I open a file:

`error: Package 'pspp-mode-1.0' is a system package, not deleting`

When I look at the backtrace, it shows core-configuration-layer.el calling delete-orphan-packages, which is I assume where this problem is ocurring.